# SwiftUI - Using 'ObservableObject' and @EnvironmentObject to Conditionally Display View

Tags: swift, class, struct, observable, swiftui

I would like to conditionally display different views in my application - if a certain boolean is true, one view will be displayed. If it is false, a different view will be displayed. This boolean is within an ObservableObject class, and is changed from one of the views that will be displayed.

**PracticeStatus.swift (the parent view)**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class PracticeStatus: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var showResults:Bool = false
}
```

**PracticeView.swift (the parent view)**

```
struct PracticeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var practiceStatus: PracticeStatus

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if practiceStatus.showResults {
                ResultView()
            } else {
                QuestionView().environmentObject(PracticeStatus())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**QuestionView.swift**

```
struct QuestionView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var practiceStatus: PracticeStatus

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ...
            Button(action: {
                self.practiceStatus.showResults = true
            }) { ... }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

However, this code doesn't work. When the button within `QuestionView` is pressed, ResultView is not displayed. Does anybody have a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to compile your code? There are several basic errors:

1. Variable `practice` does not exist in `PracticeView`. Did you mean `practiceStatus`?
2. Variable `userData` does not exist in `QuestionView`. Did you mean `practiceStatus`?
3. You are calling `PracticeView` from inside `PracticeView`! You'll definetely get a stack overflow ;-) Didn't you mean `QuestionView`?

Below is a working code:

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class PracticeStatus: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var showResults:Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var flag = false

    var body: some View {
        PracticeView().environmentObject(PracticeStatus())
    }
}

struct PracticeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var practiceStatus: PracticeStatus

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if practiceStatus.showResults {
                ResultView()
            } else {
                QuestionView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct QuestionView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var practiceStatus: PracticeStatus

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Button(action: {
                self.practiceStatus.showResults = true
            }) {
                Text("button")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ResultView: View {
    @State private var flag = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("RESULTS")
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to rename everything for the question, so those mistakes aren't in my actual code. When I run the app, and I press the button within `QuestionView`, nothing happens (although `ResultView` should be displayed). I edited my question with these clarifications.

Comment: When you call .environmentObject() you are creating a new PracticeStatus() which is different than the one being used in the if statement. Check my code to see how you should do it. Plus, it is redundant, you already have set your environemntObject. Haven't you? You do not need to set it in every view. That is the benefit of environment object.